# alter view oracle - ORA-00922

Tags: sql, oracle, view, ddl, alter

```
alter view ECOUPON.A_SAMPLE AS
select * from ECOUPON.A_COUPON_REMAINING;
```

Executed the above statement and got the following error;

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

Comment: I suggest to bookmark the [Oracle SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) where the whole SQL syntax is very good documented.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use an `alter` statement to replace a view's query in Oracle. But you could just use the `create or replace` syntax:

```
create or replace view ECOUPON.A_SAMPLE AS
select * from ECOUPON.A_COUPON_REMAINING;
```